# Block referrals back to my site

Tags: google-analytics

I have outbound links from my site to other sites. I want to block analytics trackers from seeing that those referrals came from my site. How do you block another site's analytics tool from tracking referrals from your site?

Mysite -> Another site

To make sure this is clear, I want "Another site" to not be able to see the referral came from "Mysite"

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a link shortener like bitly should do the trick but, first test bitly and see if bitly shows up in your analytics.

Hope this help

Analytics ML